# What exactly is Quantum Tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

1. What is [quantum tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling)
2. How is it possible?

I tried reading up on itbut i couldn't exactly grasp the concept.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54218/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The formal description**

To answer, you need to establish an equivalence of tunneling exponent and action of theory given for specific solution in *euclidean time*.

Suppose that you have system which is described by one-dimensional QM with coordinate $q$ and the potential $V(q)$ with $V(q_{0}) = 0$. Suppose now that such potential has barrier which divides local minimum at point $q_{0}$ and area where $V(q)$ is the same (given by point $q_{1}$). The QM state with $q = q_{0}$ is thus metastale.

As you know, the probability in the unit of time of its decay is given as
$$
\Gamma = Ae^{-S_{b}}, \quad S_{b} = 2\int \limits_{q_{0}}^{q_{1}}\sqrt{2MV(q)}dq
$$

The action for such system is given by
$$
S = \int dt\left( \frac{M}{2}\left(\frac{dq}{dt}\right)^{2} - V(q)\right)
$$
Suppose now that you perform formal transformation $t = i\tau$. Now the action takes the form
$$
S_{E} = \int d\tau \left(\left(\frac{dq}{dt}\right)^{2} + V(q)\right)
$$
Corresponding EOM takes the form
$$
M\frac{d^{2}q}{d\tau^{2}} = -\frac{\partial (-V)}{\partial q}
$$
Corresponding integral of motion
$$
E_{E} = \frac{M}{2}\left( \frac{dq}{d\tau}\right)^{2} - V(q)
$$
is called *euclidean energy*; note tht it doesn't coincide with the usual energy.

Suppose now that you are looking for the solution $q_{b}$, for which $q_{b} = q_{0}$ at $\tau \to -\infty$ and $q_{b} = q_{1}$ at $\tau = \infty$; euclidean energy for such solution is zero. Now, the action for such configuration is
$$
S_{E}[q_{b}] = 2 \int \limits_{-\infty}^{0}\sqrt{2MV(q(\tau))}d\tau = \left|d\tau = \sqrt{\frac{M}{2V(q_{b})}}dq_{b}\right| = S_{b}
$$
We come to the statement that *in euclidean time $\tau$ the solution $q(\tau) = q_{b}(\tau)$ describes tunneling effect*.

**Why is it possible?**

We see that tunneling solutions exist in euclidean time; they doesn't exist in the usual time. What is the reason for this? The reason is the energy conservation. In the usual time $t$, if we define the solution with the given energy, then it will be the same for all times; thus the solution $q_{b}$ given below doesn't exist in usual time. In euclidean time, however, the usual notion of energy isn't conserved, and existence of $q_{b}$ solution is possible.